# Unexpected use of reserved word 'import' Razzle/with-react-native-web

Tags: react-native

I use https://github.com/jaredpalmer/razzle/tree/master/examples/with-react-native-web and want to integrate with android.

I got an error 'Unexpected use of reserved word' in my android screen.

[image]

So here is my github link: https://github.com/dwncy/razzle-rn

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: Yea, i've edited it @JRK